# combine coordinates using lingo

Tags: lingo

Does anybody here who knows about Lingo Script? I'm actually a newbie on Lingo Script. And my problem is I don't have any idea on how to make an output in combining 3 coordinates. Example output: (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)

Answer (score 0):

let's make an output in Lingo.

In a fresh project, I double click frame 1 and the behavior script editor opens up.

[image: Adobe Director Lingo with behavior script on frame 1 in the timeline window]

Enter this code:

```
on exitFrame me
  put [0,1] , [2,3] 
end
```

The output in the Message window will look like this:

```
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
 -- [0, 1] [2, 3]
```

So that's how you know the syntax works, and the little XY coordinates are compiling into structures the computer understands.

Now let's try to do some maths on them.

```
on exitFrame me
  put [5,8] * [2,3] 
  put [5,8] / [2,3] 
  put [5,8] + [2,3] 
  put [5,8] - [2,3] 
  put [5,8] < [2,3] 
end
```

where the output is:

```
 -- [10, 24]
 -- [2, 2]
 -- [7, 11]
 -- [3, 5]
 -- 0
```

Okay, let us try to add a third coordinate, and change the code so it addresses the coordinates as variables.

```
on exitFrame me
  set a = [5,8]
  set b = [2,3]
  set c = [44, 66]
  put (a * b) + c
end
```

where the output is `[54,90]`.

Perhaps we want to do something that talks about the components of the coordinates, in this case, X and Y. We do this using the square bracket operator, and in this case, we pass in index, 1 (number in first slot is the X value), or 2 (number in second slot is Y value).

```
set xAverage = (a[1] + b[1] + c[1]) / 3.0
put xAverage
```